# Confusion with the definition of the form of the verb

Tags: verb-forms

I'm just starting to learn English. And I get confused with the definition of the forms and tenses of verbs.

Task: Define the form of the verb.

Cellular phones are now dialing up the Internet to provide e-mail.

"To provide" - the verb has the first form.
And "dialing up" - Present Progressive Tense. Is this a present participle? So there is no need to define the form?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong (

Comment: Welcome to English Stack Exchange! I am a little confused on what you are trying to say in the sentence. However, I can tell you that I, living in America and having spoken English my whole life, would never say 'dialing up.' Maybe you can write the sentence in your native language, and I can help you out.

Comment: @Haversine Thank you. This sentence is given from the task.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Yes, this is a present progressive because it is an ongoing activity at the present time.

Comment: @Haversine I'm sorry for the stupid question: If we are talking about defining the verb form, then you do not need to do this for "dialing up" in this sentence?

Comment: @Haversine Is this a present participle?

Comment: There is no shame at all. It is not a stupid question. I am learning a language too, and I struggle as well

Comment: I just answered the question below. It would not be present participle because it is not happening at this exact moment. It may be, but it may not. It is more of an ongoing action in the present time.

Comment: @Haversine I understood that I did not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb we are dealing with is 'dialing'. It would not be 'to provide' because 'to provide' is the purpose of 'dialing'.

And in this case, 'dialing' would be a present progressive verb because it is an ongoing action in the present time.

I hope that helps! Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Well, how can I give an answer, I'm not asked to specify the verb tense, only a verb form? Present Participle?

Comment: @JustStudy In general, the term [verb form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation#Factors_that_affect_conjugation) includes the notion of verb tense. However, it could be the case that in your particular textbook, they use it differently - we can't tell without looking at the textbook. The form of "are dialing up" is present progressive tense, third person plural, indicative mood. "dialing up" is a present participle in this context.

Comment: "Provide" is a plain (base) form, and "dialling" is a gerund-participle form. Note that "up" is **not** part of the verb, but a separate word, a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much! dial up — phrasal verb with dial verb by https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dial-up

Haversine, RuslanD thank you too. I am a beginner, so I don’t understand what is obvious to you. P. S. However, I try to make sense of it.